# I am having trouble as a newbie with C++

Tags: c++

I am new to stackoverflow so if I ask stupid questions please tolerate me. 
I am trying to build a power function manually, which I name pow_1. However, I encountered the error saying "pow_1 not all control paths return a value." 
Here is my code:

```
long int pow_1(long int original, long int hat) {
    long int total{1};
    for (int i{ 1 }; i <= hat; i++) {
        return total = total * original;
    }
}

int main() {
    long int x = 6;
    long int y = 2;
    std::cout << pow_1(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code. We can not copy/paste code when it's an image. The problem with your code is that if the `for` is never entered, you never return anything, hence "*not all control paths return a value*". Anyway note that even if it is entered, it will `return` at first iteration, so your `for` will not do what you expect it to do

Comment: if `hat` is passed into `pow_1` with a value smaller than `1` (zero or negative), the for loop will be skipped. Since there is no return after the loop, you run off the end of the function without returning a valid value, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Share your code here, so we can help

Comment: Your title is worthless. I would sugguest something which reflects the essence of your question e.g. "not all control paths return a value". You may [edit] your question to fix this. And, please, have a look at [SO: Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing and giving me tips. I will try to be better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change your code to this:

```
long int pow_1(long int original, long int hat) {
    long int total{1};
    for (int i{ 1 }; i <= hat; i++) {
        /*return */total = total * original;
    }
    // return here instead
    return total;
}
```

So you will always `return` something, and also not `return` at first `for` iteration.

---

### Edit

Note that as `hat` is a `long int`, if it is greater than `int` max value, your `for` loop will become an **infinite loop** as `i` is an `int`.

As per [this (`limits.h`)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) :

- `INT_MAX = 32767` (*depending on system and library implementation*)
- `LONG_MAX = 2147483647` (*depending on system and library implementation*)

Therefore, if `hat` is e.g. `33000`, the loop will increment `i` forever because when `i` reaches `32767` and we increment it, it will become `-32767` then `-32766`, `-32765` and keep increasing this way.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox except that I believe this is for educational purposes

Answer (score 0):

The error message is reasonably self explanatory, not all possible paths through your function return a value. If hat is 0 then no return statement will be executed and your function will have an undefined result. Presumably the intended code is:

```
long int pow_1(long int original, long int hat) {
    long int total{1};
    for (int i{ 1 }; i <= hat; i++) {
        total = total * original;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I thought if hat is 0, the function still returns total, which has the value of 1 which was initiated earlier, instead of undefined result?

Comment: @ShawnNguyen No the return value is set and the function ends when the return statement is executed. When hat is 0 there is no return statement executed so the result is undefined